# How to validate installation of a Jupyter nbextension

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a [conda recipe](https://github.com/conda-forge/vega-feedstock) that includes installation of a Jupyter nbextension. Assuming a package called `packagename`, the relevant pieces are:

```
$ python setup.py install
$ jupyter nbextension install packagename --py --sys-prefix
```

As part of the CI tests, I would like to validate that the jupyter extension was correctly installed.

Poking around the [`notebook`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook) codebase, I found these functions:

```
>>> from notebook import nbextensions
>>> nbextensions.check_nbextension('packagename')
True

>>> nbextensions.validate_nbextension('packagename')
['        - require? \x1b[31m X\x1b[0m packagename']
```

They seem to be doing something relevant, but are not so well-documented: they appear designed for internal use.

Does anybody know a good approach for validating correct installation of a Jupyter nbextension from either the shell or from within a Python script?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a notebook that uses the extension, then `jupyter nbconvert --execute` and validate the resulting HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but it seems the nbextension is loaded on the client side via a ``require()`` statement in javascript. Executing the notebook outside a browser produces this javascript code, but does not run it, and so it won't reflect whether or not the extension can be loaded.

Comment: If you need javascript, probably running selenium in headless mode will do it. Seems like an overkill though.

Comment: To be clear: I don't necessarily want to run the JavaScript. I just want to make sure the files exist where jupyter will be looking for them. This solution doesn't do that.